# Meta-programming function on ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a function that picks a specific column from a dataframe and creates a ggplot.
Example:

```
main_df1 <- starwars %>% dplyr::select(name, height, mass)
main_df2 <- starwars %>% dplyr::select(name, sex, gender, 
                                       homeworld, species)


plot_gg <- function(main_df,
                    another_df,
                    column_for_clr = c("sex", "gender", "species", 
              "homeworld")){

  #var_clf <- enquo(column_for_clr)
  new_df <-  main_df %>%
    left_join(another_df, by = "name")

  p_p <- new_df %>%
    ggplot(
      aes(x = height,
          y = mass,
          colour = as.symbol(column_for_clr))
      ) +
    xlab("Height") +
    ylab("Mass")

  classes_to_colors_10 <- c(
    "feminine"        = "red",            #  gender
    "masculine"       = "#3cb44b",      #
    "female"          = "navy",              # sex
    "hermaphroditic"  = "darkgreen",    #
    "male"            = "purple4"               #
  )

  if (column_for_clr == "sex") {
    print("colour is sex")
    p_p <- p_p +
      scale_colour_manual(values = classes_to_colors_10) +
      ggtitle("title ")
  }

  ggsave(plot   = p_p,
         device = "png",
         filename = paste0(getwd(), "/test_starwars21.png"),
         units  = "in",
         width  = 6,
         height = 4,
         dpi    = 300)
  return(p_p)
}
plot_gg(main_df1, main_df2, column_for_clr= "sex")
```

Result:

```
[1] "colour is sex"
Error in `geom_blank()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `compute_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics are not valid data columns.
✖ The following aesthetics are invalid:
✖ `colour = as.symbol(column_for_clr)`
ℹ Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add 
 `after_stat()`?
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Called from: signal_abort(cnd, .file)
```

I tried also to use `enquo`, `rlang::"!!"()`, `{{ column_for_clr }}`
but I always get some kind of error.

Is there a way to "inject" it although `ggplot` doesn't take character ?

Comment: You were close. `colour = !!as.symbol(column_for_clr)` will do the trick. You haven't actually added any geom layers to your plot though. Are you also needing a `+ geom_point()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @AllanCameron ! Yes I forgot to add the geom_point.
I will check if the "real" function works or I experience any more issues and come back